# Windows agenda view is not syncing to google calendar automatically. I need to open the calendar app before events show up

Tags: calendar, windows-10, synchronization, google-account

Please advise if this is not a platform for asking this type of question

I have an issue with the windows [agenda view](https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-see-all-your-calendars-at-a-glance-in-agenda-view/) that shows up underneath the calendar when clicking on the time in the taskbar.

When I receive a meeting invite on my gmail account, it won't show up on the agenda view automatically. To get it to show up I have to manually open the Windows Calendar app, and wait for it to load. Then if I check the agenda view, the event is there.

Is this normal behaviour?

Things I've tried:

- Ensure that google account is added to Mail and Calendar app. (removed and re-added it too)
- Ensure that mail, calendar, and contact syncing is turned on in `manage account settings`
  [image: List item]